# Redmine 500 error -Internal error An error occurred on viewing Issues/View All issues

Tags: redmine

I recently upgrade redmine 0.8 to 1.4.4 .but after up-gradation when i am going to access/view Issues Redmine 500 error -Internal error An error occurred . 
This is the Log file of redmine production -

> /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'
>
>     /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in`start'
>     /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start_thread'
>
>     /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in`start'
>     /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `each'
>
>     /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in`start'
>     /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in `start'
>
>     /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in`start'

Rendering /home/www/support.dokeos.com/www/public/500.html (500 Internal Server Error)

My setup:

- Ruby implementation and version: 1.8.7
- Rails version: 2.3.5
- Gem version : 1.3.7
- Operating system: Debian 2.6.32-5-686 i686
- Database used, and its version: mysql 5.1.61
- Ruby-aware server used: Apache2

**UPDATE:**

Error.log

```
/log# tail -f domain.com.error.log      
[Sun Aug 05 14:16:27 2012] [debug] proxy_util.c(1934): proxy: initialized single connection worker 1 in child 21737 for (localhost)    
[Sun Aug 05 14:16:27 2012] [debug] proxy_util.c(1803): proxy: worker proxy:forward already initialized     
[Sun Aug 05 14:16:27 2012] [debug] proxy_util.c(1818): proxy: grabbed scoreboard slot 1 in child 21736 for worker http://localhost:3000/     
[Sun Aug 05 14:16:27 2012] [debug] proxy_util.c(1837): proxy: worker http://localhost:3000/ already initialized    
[Sun Aug 05 14:16:27 2012] [debug] proxy_util.c(1934): proxy: initialized single connection worker 1 in child 21736 for (localhost)     
[Sun Aug 05 14:16:27 2012] [debug] proxy_util.c(1803): proxy: worker proxy:forward already initialized        
[Sun Aug 05 14:16:45 2012] [debug] proxy_util.c(1818): proxy: grabbed scoreboard slot 1 in child 21738 for worker http://localhost:3000/        
[Sun Aug 05 14:16:45 2012] [debug] proxy_util.c(1837): proxy: worker http://localhost:3000/ already initialized       
[Sun Aug 05 14:16:45 2012] [debug] proxy_util.c(1934): proxy: initialized single connection worker 1 in child 21738 for (localhost)       
[Sun Aug 05 14:16:45 2012] [debug] proxy_util.c(1803): proxy: worker proxy:forward already initialized
```

Comment: Did you migrate the database after updating? That's probably one of the most common mistakes made when upgrading Redmine.

Comment: I have done the migration , Please check the update error.log file .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try upgrading Rails and Ruby Gems. Rails 2.3.14 is required according to [Redmine install instructions](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall) for 1.4.x